# JQuery not loading JSON text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm very new to how to load JSON text with JavaScript or JQuery. I'm new to JSON overall. So I have PHP giving me some some JSON text of images I have store in my server like this:

```
[
    [{
        "name": "11_by_Shelest.jpg",
        "imgPath": "img/14567045410.jpg",
        "Img_ID": "62",
        "Date_Posted": "2016-02-28 17:09:01"
    },  {
        "name": "1227.jpg",
        "imgPath": "img/14566992060.jpg",
        "Img_ID": "39",
        "Date_Posted": "2016-02-28 15:40:06"
    }]
]
```

I want to be able to load this JSON text with JQuery and I managed to put together this function to load the script from a `text area` input field. This is my HTML:

```
<textarea name="jsonText" rows="5" class="form-control" id="jsonText"></textarea> //JSON is added here and grabbed with JQuery
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="loadImages" id="loadImages">Load Images </button>
```

This is my JQuery script.

```
$("#loadImages").click(function(e){
    var jsonText = $('#jsonText').val();
    var images = JSON.parse(jsonText);

    //console.log(images);

        var imgList= [];  
        $.each(images[0], function (name, imgPath) {
            console.log(name + " " + imgPath);
            imgList += '<img src= "' + imgPath + '" alt="' + name + '">';
        });
        $('#imgResult').append(imgList);

});
```

But it doesn't work for me. Thank you in advanced for your help!

Comment: what is the contents of images? it should be a path to the JSON file, is it?

Comment: If your JSON string is in the textarea you don't need to use `$.getJSON`. In fact that's more than likely to be causing a syntax error. The JSON sample you've posted is also not valid.

Comment: @Cruiser images is the JSON object after being parsed.

Comment: @dasjanik yeah I'm sure my code isn't correct but I'm just not just how to fix it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I ran my JSON through http://jsonlint.com/ and it told me my JSON was valid. What is invalid about it?

Comment: I did too. Given the example you included above, the issue is the trailing commas on the `Date_Posted` properties.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh yeah you're right. I removed a line before posting it on here and forgot about the commas.

Comment: Ok, no problem. the point regarding the use of `$.getJSON` remains though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how do I got about changing the code to not include the $.getJSON line. I'm honestly really new to the JSON world and I'm fairly lost.

Comment: Get rid of extra outer array or do `$.each(json[0], function(...`

Comment: @charlietfl ok I did but and it loads the image element into the html but the source is passed as [object] rather than the value of the object. I updated the JQuery code with what I changed it to.

Comment: now you need the properties of the object ... like `imgPath.name` in your string concatenation

Comment: I still got a response like this `<img src="[object Object]" alt="0">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <textarea name="jsonText" rows="5" class="form-control" id="jsonText">
        [
            [{
                "name": "11_by_Shelest.jpg",
                "imgPath": "img/14567045410.jpg",
                "Img_ID": "62",
                "Date_Posted": "2016-02-28 17:09:01"
            },  {
                "name": "1227.jpg",
                "imgPath": "img/14566992060.jpg",
                "Img_ID": "39",
                "Date_Posted": "2016-02-28 15:40:06"
            }]
        ]
    </textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="loadImages" id="loadImages">Load Images </button>
    <div id="imgResult"></div>
    <script>
        $("#loadImages").click(function(e){
            var jsonText = $('#jsonText').val();
            var images = JSON.parse(jsonText);
            var imgList = '';
            $.each(images[0], function (id, imgArray) {
                console.log(imgArray);
                imgList += '<img src= "' + imgArray.imgPath + '" alt="' + imgArray.name + '">';
            });
            $('#imgResult').append(imgList);
        });
    </script>
```

Output is two images into `DIV` with `imgResult` ID.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y6d7L0L4/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. This is the what was appended to the page `<img src="[object Object]" alt="0">` So it looks it's not passing the value of the object but the object itself.

Comment: Dude! It's freaking crazy! i copied your code over and tried it and it doesn't work for me! It's nonesense!

Comment: Did you load jQuery lib in your script?

Comment: Yeah, the Jquery runs but it inserts the img element iwht [object object] rather than the actual value like I showed you a second ago.

Comment: I'm so sorry man. I forgot I disconnect from my webserver so it wasn't uploading the changes to it. Now it works!